# How host local repository in pom.xml

Tags: jsf, maven, primefaces, spring-webflow

When ever i tried to Goals >> Compile pom.xml, I am getting the following error.

An internal error was encountered invoking the maven goal: Please check the exception details.

### org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:

1) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.httpcomponents -DartifactId=httpcore -Dversion=4.1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.httpcomponents -DartifactId=httpcore -Dversion=4.1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2

---

1 required artifacts are missing.

As per above error it suggests, Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there.
how can i provide a local repository to pom.xml.

Comment: 7 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact: 
  com.myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://subversion.myproject.com/svn/repos/m2Repo/trunk)

Comment: Can you add the output to your question, don't add it as a comment. Use the *edit* link under your question...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://wildfalcon.com/archives/2006/04/24/setting-up-a-maven2-internal-repository/) article explains what you require. Quoting from it:

A maven repository is just a directory somewhere, and thatÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s about it. In order to use it there are very few steps you need to do.

1. Choose a directory
2. Make sure its accessible via some network protocol to everyone who needs it (i.e. serve it via http or ftp or something.
3. Put the libraries you need in the directory, in a specific format.
4. Set up your maven builds to read from the repository
5. (optional) set up your maven builds to deploy your repository

To put existing libraries into the repository, use the maven deploy command.

To set up your build to read from the repository add the following xml to your pom.xml file:

servername-download
description
https://host/path

---

A detailed article for complete understanding of [Maven repositories](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... again i am confused how to use servername-download in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Maven setup works? The artifact you're looking for is in the public Maven repository:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.2/

It should be found just like any other publicly available artifact. Please check the spelling of the artifact and group in your pom file to make sure that you don't have a typo.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What does Maven print before it fails? It usually says where it's checking for the artifact - does the URL I posted above show up?

Do you see similar issues with other artifacts?

You shouldn't have to host this artifact yourself since it's publicly available. It looks like you're running Maven from an IDE - can you try to run it from command line to see if you get the same error there?

Comment: Yes I am running maven from IDE. As u suggest i tried running it from command prompt its working fine from backend. it shows above error from IDE only for newly added JAR. JARs are available in my local directory and as above i have created <dependency> for all the jars. but when ever i tried to compile pom.xml it throws error. org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:

Comment: Just for this one JAR file, or for others as well? Does Maven say where it's trying to download it from? Can you post some more of the Maven output before it fails?

Comment: here is the error from IDE...  see similar issues with other artifacts.    7 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact: 
  com.myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://subversion.myproject.com/svn/repos/m2Repo/trunk)

Answer (score 0):

To host local repository in pom.xml we have to set up maven properly.
we need to modify settings.xml and provide the local repository path in maven packages and then used it with IDE. So now on words if JAR is not available in my local repository then and then only maven tries to search in its maven repository.

please follow below blog to configure maven properly.
http://chiragsdiary.blogspot.in/2013/02/cxf-webservice-example-step-by-step.html